# Parse Cloud Code - Promises

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I'm trying to send push notifications to my users via Parse Background Job if they are in proximity of the pet that was created.

Every user in range gets crosschecked with the pets (confirmed via log) but the push notifications are sent to the wrong user or most of the time not even sent at all. I'm pretty sure I messed the promises up but can't the problem here.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
Parse.Cloud.job("locationPush", function(request, status) {

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var Pet = Parse.Object.extend("Pet");
var petQuery = new Parse.Query(Pet);
petQuery.equalTo("initialPushSent", false);
petQuery.equalTo("status", "missing");
petQuery.equalTo("deleted", false);

petQuery.find().then(function(pets) {
  var petPromises = [];
  _.each(pets, function(pet) {
    console.log("checking pet: " + pet.id);

    var petLocation = pet.get("lastSeenLocation");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.withinKilometers("lastLocation", petLocation, 50);

    query.find().then(function(users) {

        var userPromises = [];

        _.each(users, function(user) {

            var userPromise = new Parse.Promise();
            userPromises.push(userPromise);

            console.log("check user " + user.id + " with pet: " + pet.id);

            var pushPromises = [];

            if(petLocation.kilometersTo(user.get("lastLocation")) <= user.get("pushRadius")){

                console.log("send push to" + user.id);

                var promise = new Parse.Promise();
                pushPromises.push(promise);

                Parse.Push.send({
                    channels: [ "user_" + user.id ],
                    data: {
                        alert : "Neues vermisstes Tier im Umkreis"
                    }}, 
                    { success: function() {
                        console.log("push sent to: " + user.id)
                    }, 
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.log("error sending push: " + error)

                    }}).then (function(result){
                        promise.resolve();
                    }, function(error) {
                        promise.reject();
                    });

                }

                return Parse.Promise.when(pushPromises);


            });


        return Parse.Promise.when(userPromises);

    });

    petPromises.push(pet.save());
  });

  return Parse.Promise.when(petPromises);

}).then(function() {
    status.success("location Send complete"); 

}, function(error) {
    status.error("location Send Error"); 

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return` a promise from really absolutely *every* function that does something asynchronous. In your case, you dropped the promise that was returned by `query.find()`, and called `pet.save()` immediately. I guess you wanted to chain them.

Also, your `userPromise`s were never resolved, which likely is the reason that your chain failed. And your `pushPromises` array is quite unnecessary, as it only will contain at most one promise.

Also, I've used `_.map` instead of pushing to arrays, and removed the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) that you had used. It makes the `returns` more prominent, so that it's easier to spot if you forgot one.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("locationPush", function(request, status) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var Pet = Parse.Object.extend("Pet");
    var petQuery = new Parse.Query(Pet);
    petQuery.equalTo("initialPushSent", false);
    petQuery.equalTo("status", "missing");
    petQuery.equalTo("deleted", false);
    return petQuery.find().then(function(pets) {
        return Parse.Promise.when(_.map(pets, function(pet) {
            console.log("checking pet: " + pet.id);
            var petLocation = pet.get("lastSeenLocation");
            var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
            query.withinKilometers("lastLocation", petLocation, 50);
            query.find().then(function(users) {
                return Parse.Promise.when(_.map(users, function(user) {
                    console.log("check user " + user.id + " with pet: " + pet.id);

                    if (petLocation.kilometersTo(user.get("lastLocation")) <= user.get("pushRadius")) {
                        console.log("send push to" + user.id);
                        return Parse.Push.send({
                            channels: ["user_" + user.id],
                            data: {
                                alert: "Neues vermisstes Tier im Umkreis"
                            }
                        }, {
                            success: function() {
                                console.log("push sent to: " + user.id)
                            },
                            error: function(error) {
                                console.log("error sending push: " + error)
                            }
                        }); // we already got a promise here!
                    } else
                        return null;
                }));
            }).then(function() {
                return pet.save();
            });
        }));
    }).then(function() {
        status.success("location Send complete");
    }, function(error) {
        status.error("location Send Error");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, much appreciated. 
Unfortunately it now just checks the pets and never the corresponding users. 
Log: I2014-09-25T15:10:31.730Z] checking pet: KchBVkPE15
I2014-09-25T15:10:31.749Z] checking pet: VhfuUdOgT0

It should check for Pets who's Push haven't been sent yet (initialPushSent = false), check for the Users which are in Range (50km), send them the Push Notification and set the initialPushSent of the Pet to true. That's the reason the pet.save() is in place - for Debugging reasons I've removed the line which saves the state for now.

Comment: Uh, I just fixed `Parse.Push.send` where I had forgotten a `return` myself. I'm not sure how `Parse` works, but even if you forget to return a promise (so that it won't wait) it should still execute your actions - unless something went wrong and the success callbacks are never called. You will need to install at least one error handler (make the `status.error` a `console.log`). If it doesn't check users, do a `console.log(users)` to see how many were found at all. And btw, I don't see where your code sets `initialPushSent` to true - there is only the `.save()`.